# How to Detect/Bind Swipe Gestures on Windows Phone running 8.1 with Swipe.JS

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, swipe.js

This is my JS Code and works with swipe.js on most devices, how do i bind this function to work on windows phones?

```
  $(this).swipe( { allowPageScroll:"vertical",
swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {

if(direction == 'right'){
  $dots[($dots.length + activeItemIndex - 1)%$dots.length].click();
  // console.log(($dots.length + activeItemIndex)%$dots.length);
}

if(direction == 'left'){
  $dots[(activeItemIndex + 1)%$dots.length].click();
  // console.log((activeItemIndex)%$dots.length);
}
```